# How do I specify a JSON file as the data source for JasperStarter?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I am running a Jasper report using JasperStarter from the command line, using the process (`pr`) command. The version of JasperStarter is 3.1.0, which when typing `jasperstarter --help` shows that there is a `--json-query` option. The only documentation I can find is this:

http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html#The_command_process_pr

which is for 3.0.0 (and doesn't have the `--json-query` option).

I need to provide a JSON file as the data source for the report, but cannot see how this is done. I have tried the following without success:

```
jasperstarter.exe pr -f pdf -o MyReportName MyReportTemplate --json-query MyJson.json
```

How can I tell JasperStarter to use a JSON file as the data source?

Comment: I think you have to use --data-file MyJson.json to access json as data source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me with the JasperStarter 3.1.0 binaries:

`jasperstarter.exe pr -t json --json-query "Northwind.Customers" --data-file northwind.json -f pdf -o ReportOutput JsonCustomersReport.jrxml`

I have placed `JsonCustomersReport.jrxml` and `northwind.json` in the same folder where I am running the command.

The `JsonCustomersReport.jrxml` is a modified version of the one from the [JasperReports jsondatasource sample](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/demo/samples/jsondatasource/reports/JsonCustomersReport.jrxml)(I have removed the property specifying the JSON file, the query string and the subreport declaration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JsonCustomersReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="bbe115b5-a5a0-4b39-9b73-7092dc59ab6d">
    <style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Bold" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <style name="Sans_Italic" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
    <field name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="CustomerID"/>
    </field>
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="CompanyName"/>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="1" uuid="fc148b4e-50df-4a12-aa14-8505a4cfa6e1"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Normal" x="0" y="10" width="515" height="30" uuid="5bf7651c-cd6b-4eaf-b65a-1413d60faab0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="22"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Orders Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="5" width="515" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#333333" uuid="da0f1cad-f552-424b-bf19-b41cabbfa4ac"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Order List]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="5" y="5" width="100" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0aaeed6e-7ba1-4ab9-be59-d6ca702995fc"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CustomerID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="404" y="5" width="100" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="68e08f51-8c24-4c85-95f3-616e40c8ddab"/>
                <text><![CDATA[(continued)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="515" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6d76c22c-329f-4e77-a886-8580d3cb6bc1"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Bold" x="109" y="5" width="291" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9a4a0a5d-4b75-4d2b-a647-aa495101df48"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="40">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="515" height="1" uuid="1371178a-a590-4616-affe-a4e1a24bcc84"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="20" width="80" height="15" uuid="3eb302d8-0855-4f82-a666-3c9628dce372"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) + " of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="280" y="20" width="75" height="15" uuid="86f46fca-dbcb-4a60-b2f7-f8da6a4224f7"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The `northwind.json` is also the one from the [JasperReports jsondatasource sample](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/demo/samples/jsondatasource/data/northwind.json).